# iOS: self.object = nil not calling dealloc while release does

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I have a class subclassing UIView called BizView. and I have the following code

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)BizView * bizPlace;
```

/

```
@synthesize bizPlace = _bizPlace;

    -(void) showBiz
    {

        BizView * biz = [[BizView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 30.0)];
        self.bizPlace = biz;
        [biz release];

        self.bizPlace.delegate = self;
        [self.bizPlace doStuff];
    }

    -(void) removeBizView
    {
        [self.bizPlace removeFromSuperview];

        self.bizPlace = nil; //****** this does not call the dealloc of bizPlace
        // [_bizPlace release];   >>>>>>this does call the dealloc

        [self performSelector:@selector(showBiz) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
    }

    //biz view delegates
    -(void)didBizStuff:(BizView *)bView
    {
        [self.view addSubview:_bizPlace];

        [self performSelector:@selector(removeBizView) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

    }

    -(void)dealloc
    {
        self.bizPlace = nil;
        [super dealloc];
    }
```

Now according to the docs and various articles on the internet, setting self.bizPlace = nil should call the dealloc of bizPlace but this is not the case here.
However, calling [_bizPlace release] does. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Are you saying it calls `dealloc` if you do `self.bizPlace=nil` and then `[_bizPlace release]`?  Or are you saying it calls `dealloc` if you comment out `self.bizPlace=nil` and just do `[_bizPlace release]`?

Comment: self.bizPlace=nil does not call the dealloc. but when commenting out self.bizPlace=nil and writing just [_bizPlace release] dealloc is called

Comment: Did you implement the `setBizPlace:` method yourself in this class?  Or did you leave it for the compiler to synthesize?  If you implemented it yourself, edit your question to include it.

Comment: I haven't implemented it. Its done by the compiler

Answer (score 0):

So there is a  distinct difference in the 2 steps that you are comparing. When you synthesize bizPlace = _bizPlace with a strong pointer, you are allocating the memory for this particular element. At this point, you have a pointer (_bizPlace) allocated strongly as part of this class. Setting this to nil, through the synthesized setter, does not cause the class to release its member variable, however calling release on that specific variable causes _bizPlace to be released.

There are different levels of the nil setting occuring here, and that is the main thing that you should take away from this. You should note that strong properties which are synthesized to a variable, do not behave the same as a local variable allocation does. And this is due to the number of people pointing to the chunk of memory.

Comment: so if i avoid synthesizing bizPlace = _bizPlace and do away with _bizPlace all together. will this cause self.bizPlace = nil to call the dealloc or would i still need to do [bizPlace release]?

Comment: I have just tried this out with no go. dealloc is still not called

Comment: Are you using ARC?  Not using it, is when your 2 commands would not be equal.